# tmux exits with [exited] on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, zsh, tmux

The machine is a VPS that I SSH into.
The problem started when I installed [Prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto)

`tmux -v` also exits with `[exited]`
`sudo tmux` doesn't work either
I don't have a `.tmux.conf`
I seem to have a `tmux-server.log` and a `tmux-client.log` in my home directory, [Gist](https://gist.github.com/prashcr/624e1d54a13d490d27de)

**Update**: `tmux new /bin/bash` works. `tmux new /bin/zsh` doesn't.
**Update 2**: `/bin/zsh` exits with a segfault, `which zsh` gives me `/usr/bin/zsh`. `tmux new /usr/bin/zsh` doesn't work either.

Output from `strace tmux`

```
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f00bf5e4d40}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f00bf5e4d40}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGUSR2, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f00bf5e4d40}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f00bf5e4d40}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {0x7f00bfbafa20, ~[RTMIN RT_1], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f00bf5e4d40}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {0x7f00bfbafa20, ~[RTMIN RT_1], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f00bf5e4d40}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCONT, {0x7f00bfbafa20, ~[RTMIN RT_1], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f00bf5e4d40}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {0x7f00bfbafa20, ~[RTMIN RT_1], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f00bf5e4d40}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGUSR1, {0x7f00bfbafa20, ~[RTMIN RT_1], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f00bf5e4d40}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {0x7f00bfbafa20, ~[RTMIN RT_1], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f00bf5e4d40}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
getcwd("/home/play", 4096)              = 11
dup(0)                                  = 5
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {268773, 757524851}) = 0
gettimeofday({1448764191, 87929}, NULL) = 0
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 2, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=6, revents=POLLOUT}])
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {268773, 758107534}) = 0
gettimeofday({1448764191, 88462}, NULL) = 0
sendmsg(6, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(41)=[{"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377LC_CTYPE=UTF-8\0\0"..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377USER=play\0TF-8\0\0"..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377LOGNAME=play\0008\0\0"..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377HOME=/home/play\0"..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377PATH=/home/play/"..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377MAIL=/var/mail/p"..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377SHELL=/bin/zsh\0p"..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377SSH_CLIENT=210.6"..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377SSH_CONNECTION=2"..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377SSH_TTY=/dev/pts"..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377TERM=xterm-256co"..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377XDG_SESSION_ID=2"..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377LANG=en_US.UTF-8"..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377SHLVL=1\0US.UTF-8"..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377PWD=/home/play\0008"..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377OLDPWD=/tmp\0ay\0008"..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377EDITOR=nano\0ay\0008"..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377VISUAL=nano\0ay\0008"..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377PAGER=less\0\0ay\0008"..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377LESS=-F -g -i -M"..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377LESSOPEN=| /usr/"..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377TMPDIR=/tmp/play"..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377LESS_TERMCAP_mb="..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377LESS_TERMCAP_md="..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377LESS_TERMCAP_me="..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377LESS_TERMCAP_se="..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377LESS_TERMCAP_so="..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377LESS_TERMCAP_ue="..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377LESS_TERMCAP_us="..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377GREP_COLOR=37;45"..., 1040}, {"\16\0\0\0\20\4\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377GREP_COLORS=mt=3"..., 1040}, ...], msg_controllen=24, {cmsg_len=20, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_RIGHTS, {5}}, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 45844
close(5)                                = 0
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 2, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=6, revents=POLLOUT}])
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {268773, 759315479}) = 0
gettimeofday({1448764191, 89667}, NULL) = 0
sendmsg(6, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\0\0\0\0\34\10\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\0\0\0\0\0\177\0\0"..., 2076}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 2076
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 2, 4294967295) = ? ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK (Interrupted by signal)
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=32118, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
sendto(3, "\21", 1, 0, NULL, 0)         = 1
rt_sigreturn()                          = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {268773, 761009573}) = 0
gettimeofday({1448764191, 91368}, NULL) = 0
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 2, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLIN}])
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {268773, 761682098}) = 0
gettimeofday({1448764191, 92049}, NULL) = 0
recvfrom(4, "\21", 1024, 0, NULL, NULL) = 1
recvfrom(4, 0x7f00bfdd14c0, 1024, 0, 0, 0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG, NULL) = 32118
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 2, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=6, revents=POLLIN}])
                                                                                                  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {268773, 770399000}) = 0
                                                                                                                                                         gettimeofday({1448764191, 100640}, NULL) = 0
                                                                                                                                                                                                     recvmsg(6, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\10\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377", 65535}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 16
                                                                                                                                  poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 2, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=6, revents=POLLOUT}])
                                 clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {268773, 770618590}) = 0
                                                                                        gettimeofday({1448764191, 100853}, NULL) = 0
                                                                                                                                    sendmsg(6, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\t\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377", 16}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 16
                                                             poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 2, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=6, revents=POLLIN}])
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {268775, 925607357}) = 0
gettimeofday({1448764193, 255856}, NULL) = 0
recvmsg(6, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\7\0\0\0\377\377\377\377", 65535}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 16
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {268775, 925793410}) = 0
gettimeofday({1448764193, 256037}, NULL) = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f00c0687000
write(1, "[exited]\n", 9[exited]
)               = 9
getppid()                               = 32114
fcntl(0, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
fcntl(0, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)   = 0
exit_group(0)
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have anything to do with `tmux`, but rather my `zsh` configuration.

Seems to follow that `tmux` crashes because `zsh` crashes.